# DBLP getting www-homepage information from huge xml file in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm kind of new in xml, I need to get the homepage information of each author in dblp however the xml file is extremely large to deal with, around 2 gb. Here is the part I need from the file:

```
<www key="homepages/d/StephanDiehl">
<author>Stephan Diehl</author>
<title>Home Page</title>
<url>http://www.st.uni-trier.de/~diehl/</url>
</www>
```

How can I get the author name and homepage only from this xml file? Other methods I've found online are not working properly. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the desired output `Stephan Diehl` and `Home Page` ?

Comment: @pkpkpk no, it's Stephen Diehl and http://www.st.uni-trier.de/~diehl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XML element tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#) to extract the data you are interested in. The `findall` function will search for the specified tags as children of the root.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

str = """<www key="homepages/d/StephanDiehl">
<author>Stephan Diehl</author>
<title>Home Page</title>
<url>http://www.st.uni-trier.de/~diehl/</url>
</www>"""

root = ET.fromstring(str)
for element in root.findall('author'):
        print element.text

for element in root.findall('url'):
        print element.text
```